# Create iOS static library without including external framework code

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I want to create a static library in iOS. My codes rely on an external framework through

`@import frameworkA`

in one of my .m file. For the clients who are using my static library, they should have this frameworkA in their project already. So in my static library, I do not have to package frameworkA together. Anyone can suggest what I should do under such circumstances?  Btw, we are not using CocoaPods

Comment: Your static library doesn't contain frameworkA by default. So nothing you should do.

Comment: so just simply include the framework?